# How to define a non-instantiable template class?

Tags: c++, templates, language-lawyer

According to [`[temp.inst]`](http://eel.is/c++draft/temp.inst#1):

> Unless a class template specialization has been explicitly instantiated or explicitly specialized, the class template specialization **is implicitly instantiated when the specialization is referenced in a context that requires a completely-defined object type** or when the completeness of the class type affects the semantics of the program.

So if I get it right, it is possible to define a template class and *use* it without *odr-use* it. It then will not be instantiated.

**My question**: what is the more short and/or idiomatic way to define a non instantiable template class?

(I shouln'd ask two questions in one thread, but when does *"the completeness of the class type [would] affect the semantics of the program"*?)

Comment: what do you mean exactly by "non instantiable" ? if you mean a class template name that can *never* instantiate, then a simple forward declaration will do: "template<class T> struct A;// do not define !"

Comment: @MassimilianoJanes - that declares the templated `struct A`, but doesn't define it.

Comment: @Peter yep, that's why I asked what does the OP mean ... why one would 'define' an 'non-instantiable' class template ?

Comment: It is possible to define a non-instantiable templated class by making all constructors and destructors private, and ensuring that no function that is a member or a friend actually instantiates the class.   The utility of such a class is rather .... limited.

Comment: @Peter nope, you *can* instantiate a class template without constructing an instance of it ( unless this is what the OP means ), you can partially/specialize it, you can ... honestly, I still don't know what exactly the OP's looking for